# Efficient mothod to compare two folders under version control

Tags: git, svn, winmerge, kdiff3

There are two folders A and B are two working spaces of version controlled source codes (i.e. Git or SVN), and they have the same repo version or very close version. There are lots of files in the working space and it will take long time to compare the two folder directly using kdiff3 or etc software.

It is easy to generate changed file list of the folder A and B using git status. Can kdiff3 or similar software to compare the files in the list only to speed up the comparison process? Or is there any other quick method to speed up the comparison between A and B, or keep them synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular `diff` and if necessary the `--exclude=.git/`

Comment: Do you mean the Linux command `diff`? The `diff` command will show the files changed or generate a patch. But I would like to trigger `kdiff3` to do line by line compare and merge.